# mongoDB aggregation- unwind, sort and group

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Considering I have a users collection contains those documents:

```json
        {
          _id: 1,
          hobbies: ['eat', 'read', 'swim']
        },
        {
          _id: 2,
          hobbies: ['eat', 'sleep', 'swim']
        },
        {
          _id: 3,
          hobbies: ['code', 'read', 'eat']
        }
```

I want to do an aggregation on this collection so the result will be a distinct list of all those hobbies sorted in alphabetic order, for example:

```json
    {
      result: [code, eat, read, sleep, swim] 
    }
```

I've tried this solution, but it didn't work for me:

```json
    {
      $unwind: {path: "$hobbies"},
      $group: {_id: null, result: {$addToSet: "$hobbies"}}
    }
```

My problem is to sort the result field...

Comment: Your title already stated an approach. Have you tried it? Any specific difficulty you encountered?

Comment: hey @ray yes, I've tried this approach but I faced with the difficulty to sort the "addToSet" result.

I'm adding to the question the solution I've tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is very close already. Just remember `$unwind` and `$group` are separate pipeline stages. You need to wrap them with individual curly brackets. And for the sorting, you can do a `$sortArray` at the end of the pipeline.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$hobbies"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      result: {
        $addToSet: "$hobbies"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      result: {
        $sortArray: {
          input: "$result",
          sortBy: 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uU4ERgoJSUW)

Comment: Can you please explain to me why $sort stage after the $group stage is not working?

Comment: @MayAsk because a `$sort` stage means to sort at document-level(i.e. sort documents by certain field). But for your case, you are sorting in field level(i.e. sort inside the `result` array field